# Getting Ruby array of indexes which fulfill a certain condition

Tags: ruby

Problem: I have an array. I am interested in those array elements which fulfil certain conditions. I don't want a new array consisting of those array elements, but an array consisting of the indexes to those elements.

A toy example:

```
a=[3,4,8,9,11,14]
```

I want to have an array of the indexes to all the odd elements, i.e. `[0, 3, 4]`.

I came up with the following two solutions, which I both don't like much:

(1)

```
a.each_index.select {|i| a[i].odd? }
```

(2)

```
a.each_with_index.select { |el, i| el.odd? }.map(&:last)
```

I don't like variant (1), because the repetition of `a` necessitates that `a` reasonably should be a variable (and not an arbitrary expression)

I don't like variant (2), because `each_with_index` constructs an array of small arrays (pairs) consisting of value and index, although I need in the end only the index part.

Basically, I like the approach (2) somewhat better. Does anymody have an idea, how to write it more concisely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ruby version >= 2.7 you can use the `filter_map` method, like so:

```rb
a = [3,4,8,9,11,14]

a.each_with_index.filter_map {|n, i| i if n.odd?}
```

Comment: For compatibility with earlier versions of Ruby,  `a.each_index.select { |i| a[i].odd? }`.

Comment: I should have said that I'm basically running on the language extent defined by Ruby 1.9, but if I understand it corretly, this use of `filter_map` carries the same disadvantage as  approach (2).

Comment: This saves you the extra `map` transformation in your (2) implementation, and another copy of the array involved with it.

Answer (score 1):

Input

```
a = [3, 4, 8, 9, 11, 14]
```

code

```
p a.filter_map { |value| a.index(value) if value.odd? }
```

Comment: This suffers from the same problem as my approach (1), but it is certainly worth to know this alternative.